# Sleeping some draws for a moment in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I made some game as a console application, and now I want to move it to the Windows Forms.
In the console mode I use the Thread.Sleep() function to slow some elements in my game (They move from the top to the bottom of the window), but when I use the function in Windows Form application it makes the application window busy. I have to turn off the program by ALT+F4 then.
How can I fix it or is there any way to do that?

Comment: You need to use a `Timer` control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
myTimer.Interval = 5000;//This is in milli seconds
myTimer.Start();


private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs) {
{
  //Your code 
}
```

**Please note** that you should not use System.Timers.Timer

**From MSDN:** In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, the Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework. It does not say if it have been changed yet or not.

Comment: Answer is more clear here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207262/web-application-to-know-database-update/6212233#6212233

Answer (score 0):

Using `Thread.Sleep()` to control anything is like `DoEvents` from VB6 - probably a very bad idea :) Without knowing much about your application's structure, how about using a `Timer` so that you can move things at exactly the speed you want to?

If you could give some more details that may help...

Also, doing graphcs in Windows is much easier in WPF than WinForms, again depending on what your project is :)