# Web Application to know database update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

My web application (ASP.NET 4) connects to a database (SQL Server 2005). For every new row inserted in a certain table, I want the web app can do some process (like send  an email to me with new data).

How do I implement the system? My first though is having web app check the table SN column, and have a variable `lastProcessedSN`. And keep polling every minute. Is it possible to have DB notify web app when there's a new row being inserted?

Please advise, thanks.

EDIT:
Sending an email is just an example, not the exact thing I want to do. So this question is focusing on how to implement the trigger on MSSQL table insert to call my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use SqlDependency`s see

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx

&

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

Comment: This is the best approach in my book too.

Comment: Found another solution - SqlNotificationRequest.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the insert script or stored procedure to send yourself an email. If you're writing with stored procedures in SQL you can send email from there: [Send Email from SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Otherwise if you're using EF/NHibernate/Linq2SQL you could write C# code to email yourself

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest approach would be to setup a Windows scheduled task that ran every X minutes that would execute a console app you create.  Your app would select the newest rows from the table (based on timestamp, or possibly a Flag you can set) and e-mail them.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a trigger for that table so that when a new record comes to the table, it can call a dot net assembly.you can have the email sending code in your dot net assembly

Answer (score 0):

> For every new row inserted in a
>   certain table, I want the web app can
>   do some process (like send an email to
>   me with new data).

For this implementation, According to my knowledge you should use the window application.

> Is it possible to have DB notify web
>   app when there's a new row being
>   inserted?

Window application will use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Below is the sample code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
myTimer.Interval = Mention the time interval in milliseconds;
myTimer.Start();
```

Timers can be following as well.

**System.Threading.Timer**

**System.Timers.Timer**

For more information about the **Selection of Timer**, you should follow this link


[**System.Windows.Forms.Timer vs. System.Threading.Timer vs. System.Timers.Timer**](http://www.intellitechture.com/System-Windows-Forms-Timer-vs-System-Threading-Timer-vs-System-Timers-Timer/)

```
private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs) {
{
   using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
            string expression = "Parameter value";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (dr.Read()) {
                    //Your functionality
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```